com.airbnb.android.react.maps does not exist error in react-native android
I have a react-native app which has below dependencies.
"react-native-maps": "^1.15.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "^0.68.0",

when I try to run this app using react-native run-android, I get below error saying package com.airbnb.android.react.maps does not exist but I installed this package using npm/yarn.
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
WARNING: Using '--release' option could cause issues when using Android Gradle Plugin to compile sources with Java 9+. Instead, please set 'sourceCompatibility' and 'targetCompatibility' to the desired Java version, and set 'compileSdkVersion' to 30 or above. See https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#java-11
D:\RN\RNAppWithAuth\Lyfter\android\app\src\main\java\com\lyfter\MainApplication.java:17: error: package com.airbnb.android.react.maps does not exist
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;
                                    ^
D:\RN\RNAppWithAuth\Lyfter\android\app\src\main\java\com\lyfter\MainApplication.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
                 ^
  symbol: variable BuildConfig
D:\RN\RNAppWithAuth\Lyfter\android\app\src\main\java\com\lyfter\MainApplication.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        ^
  symbol:   variable BuildConfig
  location: class MainApplication
Note: D:\RN\RNAppWithAuth\Lyfter\android\app\src\debug\java\com\lyfter\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 errors

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --info option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error and I'm not able to resolve this.
I'm using below version of gradle and andorid gradle plugin
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-all.zip
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.1")
Can anyone please help me with this? I have tried all that I could find but nothing worked. Been stuck on this for days.
I tried some ways to fix this like by adding implementation line in dependencies but nothing worked
implementation project(':react-native-maps')

What version of react-native-maps and react-native do you have in your package-lock.json?

"react": "17.0.2","react-native": "^0.68.0","react-native-maps": "^1.15.1", I have mentioned the same in my post

This issue is now resolved. Below is the fix: -
For the below import error, it seems this import statement was wrong, removing this fixed the issue.

error: package com.airbnb.android.react.maps does not exist import
com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;

Correct import statement is

import com.rnmaps.maps.MapsPackage;

For the BuildConfig not being found issue, adding the below import fixed the problem.

import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;

